# Values set in a function coming up as undefined in a different state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Using ui-router. take a look at this.
starting with this in the controller:

```
  $scope.transitionResponse = {};
$scope.hello= "world"; 

  transition.makeTransitionCashOutCall(strippedUrl).then(function(response){
    //nested view will need this to build out layout
    $scope.transitionResponse.OnlineDistributionProcessUrl = response.data.OnlineDistributionProcessUrl;
    console.log(response);
    console.log($scope.transitionResponse.OnlineDistributionProcessUrl); 
    if(!response.data.OnlineDistributionProcess){  
      $scope.showDocument(transitionType);
    }else{

        //display phone no. if no url
        $state.go('rollover-options.cashout-info');
        //display url if it exists (same view ^)

    }

  });
```

The console.log for $scope.transitionResponse.OnlineDistributionProcessUrl is giving me correct value. But as soon as I drill down to another state the value is lost and i get undefined on console.logs or alerts. What is going on? really? Why is the value set getting lost? I can access hard coded values like $scope.hello fine with {{hello}} in the cashout-info view. But the other value is getting lost. I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 0):

u have not declared OnlineDistributionProcessUrl  this field in the json

```
$scope.transitionResponse = {};

instead it should be like this
 $scope.transitionResponse={
   "OnlineDistributionProcessUrl":null
 }


or you can use

$scope.transitionResponse['OnlineDistributionProcessUrl'] = response.data.OnlineDistributionProcessUrl;
```

Comment: negative, declaring doesn't help.